# Building the Windows Universal C Runtime

Tags: c++, crt

I am trying to build the Universal C Runtime that comes with the Windows 10 SDK.

I created a project and added source code from this directory:

%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.16299.0\ucrt

I encountered errors. I followed and fixed the trail of errors. But eventually I got errors about overloaded functions and missing headers that don't seem to exist on my computer:

```
(ClCompile target) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\inc\corecrt_internal.h(102): error C2556: '__crt_stat
e_management::dual_state_global<int> *__p__fmode(void)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'int *__p
__fmode(void)' [C:\src\ucrt\build\time.vcxproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\inc\corecrt_internal.h(102): error C2371: '__p__fmode
': redefinition; different basic types [C:\src\ucrt\build\time.vcxproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\inc\corecrt_internal.h(1920): fatal error C1083: Cann
ot open include file: 'corecrt_internal_state_isolation.h': No such file or directory [C:\src\ucrt\build\ti
me.vcxproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\inc\corecrt_internal.h(102): error C2556: '__crt_stat
e_management::dual_state_global<int> *__p__fmode(void)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'int *__p
__fmode(void)' [C:\src\ucrt\build\time.vcxproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\inc\corecrt_internal.h(102): error C2371: '__p__fmode
': redefinition; different basic types [C:\src\ucrt\build\time.vcxproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\inc\corecrt_internal.h(1920): fatal error C1083: Cann
ot open include file: 'corecrt_internal_state_isolation.h': No such file or directory [C:\src\ucrt\build\ti
me.vcxproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\inc\corecrt_internal.h(102): error C2556: '__crt_stat
e_management::dual_state_global<int> *__p__fmode(void)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'int *__p
__fmode(void)' [C:\src\ucrt\build\time.vcxproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\inc\corecrt_internal.h(102): error C2371: '__p__fmode
': redefinition; different basic types [C:\src\ucrt\build\time.vcxproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\inc\corecrt_internal.h(1920): fatal error C1083: Cann
ot open include file: 'corecrt_internal_state_isolation.h': No such file or directory [C:\src\ucrt\build\ti
me.vcxproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\inc\corecrt_internal.h(102): error C2556: '__crt_stat
e_management::dual_state_global<int> *__p__fmode(void)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'int *__p
__fmode(void)' [C:\src\ucrt\build\time.vcxproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\inc\corecrt_internal.h(102): error C2371: '__p__fmode
': redefinition; different basic types [C:\src\ucrt\build\time.vcxproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\inc\corecrt_internal.h(1920): fatal error C1083: Cann
ot open include file: 'corecrt_internal_state_isolation.h': No such file or directory [C:\src\ucrt\build\ti
me.vcxproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\inc\corecrt_internal.h(102): error C2556: '__crt_stat
e_management::dual_state_global<int> *__p__fmode(void)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'int *__p
__fmode(void)' [C:\src\ucrt\build\time.vcxproj]
...
```

I wasn't able to find any documentation about building the Universal C Runtime.

Am I on the wrong track? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like C++. Are you sure?

Comment: That recent edit of @Neil was obviously wrong. How's something like `e_management::dual_state_global<int>` related to [tag:c] actually??

Comment: @user I've approved your edit. Madly, if you hadn't made an edit I could have reverted mine, but since you have made one, I can't. This whole approve thing for people without enough rep to actually edit needs to be completely re-thought, if you ask me.

Comment: @Neil I see that's sometimes a hard border of acknowledging for users, who are used to simply edit, without need to get them reviewed. You can siimply override that with your privileges. A reworking of that mechanism seems to be reasonable.

Comment: Interesting. A quick readup on the Windows Universal C Runtime leaves me wondering why it's called Windows Universal C Runtime. I mean, that's what caused the confusion.

Comment: Why are you trying to build this in the first place?

Comment: I am hoping to explore the performance properties of enabling the compile/linking protection Control Flow Guard on these libraries. Unlike some other compile-time protections, like Address Space Layout Randomization, Data Execution Prevention, and others, CFG seems to bear a runtime cost. The redist libraries packaged with the Windows 10 SDK have not been compiled with CFG.

Comment: You will probably never be able to decently use your custom build anyway, it's pretty much an OS component that can be updated and changed at will, so it seems to me like you're trying to do something complex for little to no possible merit. But anyway, the question stands, and can be answered if anyone knows how. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In older versions, Microsoft shipped the full C runtime source, and it was possible to rebuild it yourself. However, in more recent versions, Microsoft has removed support for rebuilding it outside of Microsoft ([source](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/private-ucrt-from-source/113492#T-N116600)). Part of how they have done that, is by not shipping certain key files required to build it, such as `corecrt_internal_state_isolation.h` (as you've discovered).

If you just want to change one particular file, you may be able to (with some hacking) recompile just that file – see [this blog post](https://colinfinck.de/posts/that-time-i-had-to-patch-the-universal-crt/) for an example.

In theory, one could construct something functionally equivalent to any missing files (including `corecrt_internal_state_isolation.h`) through trial and error, intelligent guesswork, maybe even some reverse engineering of the binary. It would be a lot of work, but maybe someday someone out there will feel attracted to the challenge.